# Slick JS not showing dots

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I'm using [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

For some reason I can't seem to get the dots to show.

This is what I have.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML Markup**

```
<div class="single-item">
  <div><img src="img/shadow.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="img/shadow.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="img/shadow.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

**Calling and options**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-item').slick({
           dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 500,

    });
});
```

Weirdly it groups the images into a slideshow. If I test whether it's working with autoplay the carousel works. The dots are just not showing, even though I call them.

**style.css**

CSS in a [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dr8x7oLg/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I already test at jsfiddle. The dot have showing.Using same option like you do. Can you try remove your style.css and test if it work or not. I think maybe have issue with css or you can share the style.css content here.

http://jsfiddle.net/bo37aLbz/

Code

```
$(function () {
    var slickOpts = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        autoplay: true
    };

    // Init the slick    
    $('.single-item').slick(slickOpts);
});
```

Comment: you're correct. It appears something is preventing it within my CSS. Anyway of finding out what? I'll edit question and add CSS.

Comment: Try move your style.css to the last one and see the dot shown up or not. I think have issue with "li" css inside your style css. Try remove this code

`ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 310px;
} `

Comment: That worked! ( removing code) Thanks. Dots don't look right now. Seems to show broken characters. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46025079/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-26%20at%2019.28.46.png

Answer (score 6):

Experienced the same problem. It was caused by setting `overflow:hidden` for the slideshow wrapper in my CSS. The dots were there, but not visible.

By default Slick position dots absolutely to `bottom: -45px`.

I think lot of people will end up by setting `overflow:hidden` in order to prevent displaying all slides in one big column before Slick is initiated and hides the ones not meant to be displayed at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I've set `overflow: hidden`, and the `customPaging` disappeared.
`customPaging` relies entirely on the dots setting.

Answer (score 0):

**Put these lines of code in head of the page in script tags :**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

   $('.slicker1').slick({   

        centerMode:false,     
        draggable:false,    
        arrows:true,    
        autoplay:true,
        autoplaySpeed:1500,     
        slidesToShow:1,     
        slidesToScroll:1,   
        dots:true,

    }); 

 });
```

Comment: I would say this is the correct answer for a newer version ? The dots weren't in my DOM like previous comments said. So now it is not visible by default ?